# Windows.print displaying print dialog box but printing blank page in fire fox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using classic asp, on one page I am using the window.print() method to print a page. The script I am using displays the print dialog box and will print fine in IE however with FF it just prints a blank page

If I use control + p to print the page in fire fox then the page is printed without a problem so its not a rendering problem

here is the script I am using:

```
function printform(url) {

    var windowReference = window.open(url, "Header", 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no');
    if (window.print)
        windowReference.print()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

This is a work around i came up with thanks to Prusse

function printform(url) {

```
var windowReference = window.open(url, "Header", 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no');
if (window.print)
    if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {

  windowReference.onload = function(){ windowReference.print(); } 
}
else {
    windowReference.print()
}
```

}

Comment: My guess is at the time you call `windowReference.print()` the page is not loaded yet.  Try `windowReference.onload = function(){ windowReference.print(); };`.

Comment: This worked for Fire fox but now in IE the dialog box does not even appear...

Answer (score 4):

It stopped working because IE already has loaded the document and already fired the onload event. You could check if the document is already loaded and simply call print and if it isn't and the event handler.

```
function printform(url) {
    var windowReference = window.open(url, "Header", 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no');
    //if (window.print)
    //  windowReference.print();
    if (windowReference.print){
        var done = false;
        if (windowReference.document && windowReference.document.readyState){
            var rs = windowReference.document.readyState;
            if ((rs === 'complete') || (rs === 'loaded')){
                done = true;
                windowReference.print();
            }
        }
        if (!done){
            if (windowReference.addEventListener){
                windowReference.addEventListener('load', function(){ this.print(); });
            } else{
                windowReference.onload = function(){ this.print(); };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I decided to just test if the user was using a fire fox browser, here is the code i used: 'function printform(url) { var windowReference = window.open(url, "Header", 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no'); if (window.print) if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") { windowReference.onload = function(){ windowReference.print(); } } else { windowReference.print() } }'